# If you have two chains of same length and you add your block to one chain while n/w selects the other

Tags: transactions, blockchain, block

If you have two block-chains of same length and you add your block to one chain while the network selects the other chain, what happens to the transactions in your block ?

Answer (score 0):

That block and the transactions in that block will not be accepted as confirmed by the network.

Few things can happen with these transactions though:

- some or all of these transactions are possibly included in the other chain
- the transactions that are not included in other chain are returned to the pool of unconfirmed transactions, waiting to be included in some future block
- if conflicting transaction is included in other chain than the transaction will be considered invalid (as a double spend) and will be removed from the pool and will not be included in the future